# PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver doesn't work when I take a screenshot

Tags: ios, swift, gallery

I have a gallery that shows every photo/video from my camera roll in fullscreen.
I added a `PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver` to my app, so if something changes in the library it should also change in my gallery. You can navigate through the photos/videos with sliding.
If I exit my app (pressing the home button not manually close it), take a photo with the camera and open it again everything works fine.
Now my problem is that if I take a screenshot, and didn't exit the gallery before, the camera roll also changes and then the program doesn't work well anymore.

This code I use for observering the camera roll:

`PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().registerChangeObserver(self)` and this function:

```
func photoLibraryDidChange(changeInstance: PHChange) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.updateFetchResult()
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to authorize it

```
 PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
        if status == PHAuthorizationStatus.Authorized{
            PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().registerChangeObserver(self)
    }
```

Also check if you have added `PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver` in your class.